# How to return JSON data from an Ajax call NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, json

I am making calls to my server with Ajax. The data is returned and sent to a callback method.  I want to have the response data formatted in data.  How can I do this? I'm assuming it involves XML -> JSON conversion.  I do not want to use the jQuery ajax method.

Comment: If you're already making calls to the server with ajax, why didn't you post that code ?

Comment: with `xmlhttprequest` and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will not have anything to do with the process you must perform server side. Regardless of your server side technology, you will need to convert the result into the JSON format.

The process of conversion is known as ["serialization"<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Use a serializer to convert your server side object into JSON format so that you may use it again when it is returned to your client side script.

<sub>1. Serialization - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</sub>

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions :
put it in a global variable or use a callback
You cannot return a xmlhttp response (tried few days ago, used jQuery it saved my life.)